# recover data after using dd command

Tags: external-hard-drive, data-recovery, dd, testdisk

Hi I have an Iomega HD for mac. I was writing a ubuntu server image to another drive but accidentally selected my 500GB Iomega with my files on it. The command I ran was:

```
sudo dd if=/Users/myuser/Desktop/ubuntu/ubuntuserver.img of=/dev/rdisk1 bs=1m
```

this shouldve been another disk.

I have downloaded testdisk but have no idea how to recover using it.

what are my best options for retrieving the data?

Comment: Do you have a backup?

Comment: just ran photoRec i am starting to see some of my files being recovered!

Comment: You should have indicated that you aborted the "dd" part way through then !!!  A fully "dd"'d disk will leave previous little to recover. Good on you for using photorec though !

Comment: What is the size of the ubuntu server image file?

Comment: I didnt abort the "dd" the image is only 722 MB

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recovering Ubuntu after filesystem was overwritten using dd](http://superuser.com/questions/338240/recovering-ubuntu-after-filesystem-was-overwritten-using-dd)

Answer (score 5):

Quite simply, its probably impossible *if* dd finished its work -if you stopped it partway, any data that wasn't overwritten should be recoverable. Testdisk is most useful when a system got formatted - and this usually involves 'marking' sectors as not in use, rather than erasing them. With modern drives, despite [what the guttmann paper](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/pubs/secure_del.html) says, overwriting the data is [extremely likely to leave data irrecoverable](http://www.nber.org/sys-admin/overwritten-data-gutmann.html). DD overwrites data and as such, there's no practical way you can recover your data, short of recovering off backups.

Unfortunately, forensics is *tricky*. photorec is a good start, but you probably need to try things like [scalpel](http://www.digitalforensicssolutions.com/Scalpel/) and [foremost](http://foremost.sourceforge.net/) too. If the data has value, its probably worth getting a quote from a professional drive recovery company too.

Comment: Guttman says that it _might_ be possible to get the overwritten data back, with a _massive_ investment (a few kilobucks per megabyte, at least).

Comment: That was assuming older data densities. I suppose if he'd just started running dd, and stopped it in time, testdisk might help, but thats a different scenario from 'I overwrote my entire drive with dd'